# Hibernate annotations and DTOs

Tags: hibernate, design-patterns, dao, dto

I have a design question about the use of Hibernate annotations and DAO pattern. The DTO are supposed to represent entities of the data model. The DAOs are interfaces that define operations on these DTOs. The DAOs implementations are classes that implement the DAO interfaces, and implement the operations defined by these interfaces (for example using Hibernate/MySQL).
My question is : How can I use Hibernate annotations in this case? If I annotate directly the DTO, I couple my DTO with the Hibernate framework which is a bad practice I think.

Maybe it's a simple question but the problem is interesting.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter or supposed "independance" vs. ease of use. Either you choose to use Hibernate or another JPA engine, and you indeed need to have annotations on your entities and have the hibernate jars in your classpath to use them. Or you choose to be completely independant of JPA/Hibernate, but you have to implement the whole persistence yourself.

My opinion is that sacrificing the ease of use and productivity gains offered by JPA just to avoid some jars in the classpath is a bad choice. But YMMV.

Comment: I was thinking that one project can be dedicated to the not annotated DTOs and the DAO interfaces. And, another project dedicated to Hibernate implementations of the DAOs with the XML mapping file of Hibernate. So, the DAOs interface and DTOs are completely independent of a specific implementation. Do you think it's a best practice to use XML mapping file of Hibernate in this case?

Comment: Hibernate doesn't use DTOs. It uses entities. Once you get an entity from the Hibernate session, it stays attached to the session, and all the changes you apply to the entity are automatically made persistent in database, without the need to call any DAO.update() method. And all the associations from one entity to others are automatically loaded lazily by just navigating into the object graph. You may detach the entities (and thus make them act as DTOs), but then you lose a very big part of what makes JPA so useful.

Comment: I understand from your comment that the DAO pattern and Hibernate are "incompatible". Because we can update the entity through its methods with Hibernate, we don't need to use DAOs in this case?

Comment: The DAOs are still useful to persist transient entities, merge detached ones, and find entities in the database using queries. It allows decoupling the business logic from the persistence logic and makes testing of both easier. But a Hibernate DAO won't be used exactly the same way as a JDBC DAO. Don't code all your Hibernate application with the idea that maybe some day you'll have to switch everything to JDBC. There's a 99.99% probability that it will never happen. And if it happens, removing annotations will be your easiest task.

Comment: I've posted this question because there was something that disturbed me: the fact that the DTO was annotated with Hibernate and that these DTOs are known from my business logic that also needs to be coupled to Hibernate because these annotations. Do you think it's a good practice to let the business logic or presentation layer to be coupled to Hibernate? (Sorry for the delay but I'm still on the question.)

Comment: I think it really doesn't matter. What the user wants is to have a working app. What the client wants is to have an app developed fast. The fact the hibernate jars are in the classpath is the least of their concern.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using annotations from javax.persistence package you are **NOT** coupling your code with Hibernate (you would however when using org.hibernate annotations, because they rely on 3rd party libraries).

Note that annotations are just meta information not affecting your design (you don't force classes to implement methods like with interfaces), you just annotate them with additional information for certain purposes.

Client of annotated classes isn't forced to couple his code with additional dependencies as long as annotations belong to standardized java api (javax.persistence in this case).

Comment: Yes, but if I use javax.persistence package i'm coupling my code to JPA and there are implementations of the DAOs that not use JPA nor Hibernate. My idea was to leave the DTOs COMPLETELY independent of a specific implementation. What do you think?

Comment: If having totally uncoupled code to anything (even JPA) is your top priority, use hibernate XML mappings. They are more verbose and less comfortable (at least for me), but fit your requirements. But remember, annotations are here for simplyfying things, so you should think carefully whether your jpa-coupled classes will ever appear in non-jpa project.

Comment: Okay, so I understand that I need to think about the future of my DTOs. If the only way we'll use to persist them is JPA/Hibernate, use of annotations is appropriated. Otherwise, the use of XML mapping in an Hibernate specific project makes mapping configuration easier.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, DTOs are object-relation mapping between Hibernate and your database tables, if that is the case I believe you better have your DTO objects annotated.

Answer (score 0):

From Wikipedia:

> In a traditional EJB (Enterprise JavaBeans) architecture, DTOs serve dual purposes: first, they work around the problem that entity beans pre-ejb 3.0 are not serializable; second, they implicitly define an assembly phase where all data to be used by the view are fetched and marshalled into the DTOs before returning control to the presentation tier.[citation needed]; a third reason of using DTOs could be that certain layers of the application should not be able to access the underlying data access objects, and hence change the data.

Thus DTO are the objects which are created from entities and are used by the presentation layer (JSP, for example, should access DTO-s and not the entities directly). So, you should annotate not the DTO-s but your Entity classes, and then provide the code to translate Entities to DTO-s.

Comment: So in your case you have both Hibernate entities and DTOs, both represented by classes. What happens when you want to modify the model? You need to work twice, at the DTOs level and at the Entities level?

Comment: that's right; note that also in the case which the Wikipedia article cited refers to as "a traditional EJB (Enterprise JavaBeans) architecture", whenever you change your entity EJB, you have also to change the corresponding DTO.